# Difficulty resolving missing Android SDK APIs in iOS SDK during J2objc translation #2309

Tags: java, android, ios

Description:

When translating from Java to Objective-C using the J2objc project, there arises a challenge when certain Android SDK APIs in Java cannot be found in the iOS SDK for Objective-C. This occurs during the translation process, as some APIs may not have direct equivalents or may be implemented differently in the iOS environment.

Problem:

When using J2objc to convert Java code to Objective-C, there are instances where Android SDK APIs utilized in the Java codebase do not have direct counterparts in the iOS SDK.
This leads to compilation errors or inconsistencies in the translated code, hindering the seamless migration of Android applications to iOS.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: *How can I deal with this problem?* - 1. understand android's code 2. port it to iOS  ... on j2objc's github page "What J2ObjC Is/What J2ObjC isn't" is directly written that this tool is not suitable for how you wana use it

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve mapping from Android API to iOS API? I'm wondering if in the absence of such mapping, would everyone really create their own API to meet Android's requirements?

Comment: Yes.... or they are using cross platform frameworks